# Which version of mod_perl should I install on IHS 7

Tags: mod-perl, ihs

We have a IHS box that requires me to install mod perl.

I'm trying to work out if I should install mod_perl 1 or 2.

apachectl -v returns:

```
Server version: IBM_HTTP_Server/7.0.0.11 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 23 2010 12:49:10
```

http://perl.apache.org/download/index.html  suggests that:

mod_perl 1 is for use with Apache 1.3.x  and 
mod_perl 2 is for use with Apache 2.0.x / 2.2.x

Any ideas about IHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_HTTP_Server says:

IBM HTTP Server 7.0
7.0.0.0, 15 March 2009 (Apache 2.2.11 based)